# Change Ubuntu's purple login screen to GNOME 3.36's

Tags: gnome, login, 20.04, lock-screen, gdm

My **login screen** on boot is **Ubuntu's purple** login screen. On suspend, the login screen is **GNOME's new one**, with the blurred desktop bg.
How can I **get rid of Ubuntu's** and only have GNOME's?

- Settings app reads: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME 3.36.1.
- `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` reads `/usr/sbin/gdm3`, though I don't know what's the default in the Wayland case.
- `sudo gdm3 --version` reads `GDM 3.34.1` (why not 3.36.1?)

Note: On Ubuntu's log in screen I can pick GNOME (which I use)/GNOME Xorg/Ubuntu/Ubuntu Wayland. I have a feeling this is related, and I'd basically like to get rid of everything Ubuntu (other than the OS ofc) and **only keep GNOME**.

EDIT: [a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbn3qd7gufvd6gj/VID_20200506_221415.mp4?dl=0) / [screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wirqm36n5nkfzbi/Screenshot%20from%202020-05-07%2013-22-57.png?dl=0) showing the GNOME lock screen at the beginning changing to the Ubuntu one after clicking the Switch User button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mean just the background picture. By GNOME's login screen I mean [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vocxt3SUA4), and by Ubuntu's [this](https://bit.ly/2Wz4ml6). Even if they were the same theme (which they aren't, in Ubuntu's the WiFi menu is white instead of dark) they are still two different instances of it. When I click on the user icon on the bottom right of GNOME's screen, it gets stuck for a few seconds and then changes to Ubuntu's. It seems like two different lock/login screens are competing on my system...

Comment: No, I added a video to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. your video made it clear.

for this acheivment you need to run the below command and choose the corresponding number for this file. `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource
```

Example output:

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource 
    [sudo] password for admin: 
    There are 4 choices for the alternative gdm3-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource).

      Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
      0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
      1            /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/theme/blur.gresource               0         manual mode
      2            /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/theme/focalgdm3.gresource          0         manual mode
    * 3            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
      4            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

[image]

To remove the "UbuntuLogo" image from the screen, open the file `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults` and navigate to this section..

```
# Login manager options
# =====================
[org/gnome/login-screen]
#logo='/usr/share/images/vendor-logos/logo-text-version-128.png'
```

and uncomment the last line.. which should look like this..

```
# Login manager options
# =====================
[org/gnome/login-screen]
logo=''
```

[image]

or if you wish to put your own image..

```
# Login manager options
# =====================
[org/gnome/login-screen]
logo='/home/admin/myubuntu.jpg'
```

[image]

Comment: I really thank you for your help!
Though even choosing the ```gdm3-theme.gresource ``` alternative didn't fix it. I still have the Ubuntu login screen taking over after clicking the Switch User button or on boot, [see picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wirqm36n5nkfzbi/Screenshot%20from%202020-05-07%2013-22-57.png?dl=0).

Comment: Yes, but I have two login screens: one is Ubuntu's version of GNOME and one is the pure GNOME. The gear icon lets me choose a session.

Comment: Ok, so how can I use GNOME's login screen (which clearly exists) instead of Ubuntu's version? Even if I enable "automatic login" in the settings, Ubuntu still controls the login screen.

Comment: So if this is the normal state I'll just keep it this way. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't interested in that. My question stemmed at misunderstanding.