# Custom GDM3 Logo In Ubuntu 20.04 (With GNOME Shell Theme)

Tags: gnome-shell, gdm, dconf

I'm Ronaldo, I'm having a serious problem, I installed the fresh ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I also installed the GNOME vanilla, and the GDM3 Also, then I changed the theme of the GDM3 yaru to gnome shell, with a gray background with blue selections, then the logo is not there, I logged into my account, I installed dconf, I went to org/gnome/login-screen, and I chose the logo of my preference, I logged out my account, and nothing happened! Please help me?

Comment: are you looking to change/show the logo in place of "Ubuntu" at the bottom center of the screen?

Comment: Yes, but I changed the login theme by yaru to the default GNOME Shell theme, but the logo wasn't there

Comment: You want custom one? What is the resolution of that one??

Comment: Yes, I want resolution with 347x96

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1236448/739431